# Manipulating String from Database

Tags: php, sql-server, string

I have a table which has fields `studentId` and `AttendaceStatus`.

The `AttendanceStatus` is a `varchar(2)` type string. It has values like "PPPPAAAPPP".

How can I count the number of 'P's and 'A' and show it in a PHP file?

Comment: How the field can be `VARHCAR(2)` and hold value of "PPPPAAAPPP"? It will give error.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use sql query :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN AttendaceStatus = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS present, SUM( CASE WHEN AttendaceStatus = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS absent
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple loop counting the occurrences of characters in a given string:

```
<?php

$input = 'PPPPAAAPPP';

$counts = [];
foreach (str_split($input) as $char) {
  if (isset($counts[$char])) {
    $counts[$char]++;
  } else {
    $counts[$char] = 1;
  }
}

print_r($counts);
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Array
(
    [P] => 7
    [A] => 3
)
```